# My application want to know twitter account changed or not in iphone setting - iphone sdk

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, twitter

Myapplication want to know twitter account changed or not in iphone setting -> twitter. Please check the below image
[image]

Requirement: My application signin with twitter. After 10days i remove the twitter account from settings and add different twitter account then open my application.

application want to know twitter account changed or not.
Is it passable?
Can anyone help me.
Thanks..

Comment: Are you using the twitter sdk?
https://dev.twitter.com/

Comment: yes,i am using twitter sdk. @HalR